# Cannot Link to part of page with MUI 5 Drawer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm simply trying to link to a specific part of my first page when the user clicks on the *Shop* button in the navigation Drawer but it doesn't do anything at all:

[image]

This is the code for the MUI 5 Drawer component:

```
    <Drawer
      anchor="left"
      open={open}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      PaperProps={{
        sx: {
          background: "linear-gradient(to top, #9C685B44, #9C685Bff)",
        },
      }}
    >
      <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <ChevronLeftIcon sx={{ color: "white" }} />
      </IconButton>
      <Divider />
      <List>
/////////////////////////////////
        <ListItem>
          <Button
            // Linking to Products Section
            href="#products"
            startIcon={<PhoneAndroidIcon />}
            sx={{
              color: "white",
              fontFamily: "Montserrat",
            }}
          >
            Shop
          </Button>
        </ListItem>
//////////////////////////////
        <ListItem>
          <Badge color="error" badgeContent={badgeNumber}>
            <Button
              startIcon={<ShoppingCartIcon />}
              sx={{
                color: "white",
                fontFamily: "Montserrat",
              }}
            >
              Cart
            </Button>
          </Badge>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Drawer>
```

And in that respective section, I have added an id with the value of products to the container:

```
<Container maxWidth="xl" id="products">
   ...
</Container>
```

Even using the anchor tag results in the same issue.

**Is there anyway to fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) and [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to handle this. Remove the `href` from your `Button` component, and instead use its `onClick` method to call the following:

```
// id is your section names (e.g. 'products')
// url is optional, and if not specified, is set to the document's current URL

const onNavClick = (event, id, url) =>
{
    let element = document.getElementById(id)
    event.preventDefault()
    element.scrollIntoView()
    window.history.pushState(id, id, url)
}
```

There are various other options you can pass into `scrollIntoView`, and you can find out more about the available options by following the link above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Is it necessary to have the `history.pushState` part? Because right now upon pressing "back", it takes me to the part I was, before I clicked on the Nav button